# Poisson Distribution Consecutive Event Disjointed by Less Than x Time

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

In a network of packages there are two transmission lines.One has λ=10 packages/s and Number Two has λ=20p/s.In an interval of 5 seconds 100 packages arrived.

So the first question is whats the probability of 40p coming from line 1 and 60 from line 2.
I figured it would be

P<sub>t</sub>=(P(5)<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>=40)+(P(5)<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>=60)

And the second problem is the calculate the probability of two consecutive packages being separated by less than 10 ms.

I Have no idea how to solve this once since the lines overlap right?Should I calculate a poisson distribution for two consecutive packages being one from line 1 and another from line 2, and another one with 2 from line 2?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each packet has a $10/(10+20)=1/3$ chance of being from line $1$. So the probability that of the first $100$ packets, $40$ of them are from line $1$ is given by a binomial distribution:
$$
\binom{100}{40}(1/3)^{40}(1-1/3)^{100-40} \approx 0.03075091.
$$

For the second question, recall that the superposition of two Poisson processes is again a Poisson process with its rate the sum of the rates of the constituent processes. So we may consider a single Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 30$ (per second). The time between consecutive arrivals is exponentially distributed with the same rate $\lambda$, so the probability that two arrivals are separated by less than $1/100$ seconds is given by

$$
1-\exp(30\cdot 1/100) \approx 0.1845155.
$$

Comment: Would it be possible to solve question 1 using a poisson process?I say this because this exercice was in a Poisson Chapter of my book

Comment: The time between arrivals in a Poisson process is exponentially distributed. This is a fundamental property of Poisson processes...